# how to use tables in Matlab

Tags: matlab, uitableview, matlab-deployment

I want to know please how can I fill in a table, row by row, by numbers, and then to color in each row the cell that has the higher number in it.

I searched the web a little and found this "set(handles.uitable2, 'Data', {5,6,4})" but this is not helping me because i need to fill in row by row, and in this method the row data is been replace.

this is the table. as you see there is 7 rows and 10 columns. in each columns there is the correlation score of the plate digit against the samples digits (0-9).
[image]

this is how I call the correlation function`[scores] = compute_corr(digit);` I'm executes this call 7 times for each plate digit. scores is an array that saves in each call the correlation scores and digit is one digit from the plate.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe there's a way to update the data incrementally. So you should maintain an array containing your data, update that row by row, and call `set(...,'Data',actualData)` when it changes.

Comment: @Gareth McCaughan thanks for your answer, but when I'm trying to update the table it always replaces the first row. I tried also to put all the data at once but again it put all the data in first row.

Comment: Could you give a brief bit of sample code that didn't work for you? I just tried and it works fine for me: `t=uitable; set(t,'Data',{1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9});` and then a similar `set` with different data.

Comment: @Gareth McCaughan maybe it's because my array ins't contain ';'. how can I concatenate ';' to my array? thanks.

Comment: So what *is* your array? The `;` just indicates starting a new row in a 2d array. If your array has only one row then the resulting table will have only one row, and there's nothing wrong with that. Could you give a brief bit of sample code that didn't work for you, and explain what you hoped it would do and what it actually did?

Comment: @Gareth McCaughan I'm at work right now and all the files is in my home computer. thanks for your response. my array is just test numbers that I get from correlation function, I'm trying to build a "Optical Character Recognition" system, so for every number in the license plate I'm execute the correlation function and gets an array of numbers represent the score for every number from 0 to 9. because of that my array doesn't contain the sign ';'.

Comment: The `;` is not part of the array. It's part of how the array is written. It indicates the point at which one row ends and the next begins. It sounds as if the array you're constructing has 10 elements, one per digit; so how do you want the numbers to appear in the table? Are you hoping to get them rearranged into (say) a 5x2 shape or something? Or to have other information in the table besides the correlation values?

Comment: @Gareth McCaughan i'm dealing with 7 digit plate. so my table would be 7x10 size. every row represent one digit from the the plate and the columns represent the score that the correlation function returns for every digit(0-9). now let's say that I'm maintain one big array of all the scores of all the digits, if I'm use the command "set(...,'Data',actualData)", the table expands and all the data displayed in the first row only. if I can concatenate the sign ';' to represent the rows it would be great. thanks again.

Comment: The array of scores needs to be the same shape as your table. There is no question of concatenating `;` signs; that's just an artefact of how you type in 2-dimensional arrays when interacting with MATLAB. The `;` is no more a part of the array than the `[]` or `{}` around it. You need to have a 7x10 array containing the correlations; when you compute a particular correlation you need to say, e.g., `correlations(platePosition,digitNumber) = corr;`; and you need to set that 7x10 array as the `Data` for your `uitable`. How does that compare to what you're currently doing?

Comment: @Gareth McCaughan if my correlation function returns an array how should I place it in the "(platePosition,digitNumber)"? as you see my Matlab skills is not very good.

Comment: Please explain (1) what arguments you provide to your correlation function, (2) what it returns, and (3) exactly what you want in your table.

Comment: So if I'm understanding you correctly, the value returned from `compute_corr` is actually an array containing 10 correlation values, one for each of the 10 digits 0..9? In which case, you need to put those into a row of the array you're building; something like `data(digitPos,:) = compute_corr(digit);`.

Comment: @Gareth McCaughan is there effective way to define an array? or the only way is to do like this: "scores = [1,2,3 ; 4,5,6; 7,8,9;];" in case of 3x3 array. and thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @Gareth McCaughan thanks it works. I did like this: "scores = zeros(7,10)" to define an 7x10 array.